# Image hover not working..on pure css

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="headermenu">
    <ul >
        <li id="menu1"><a href="#"><img src="images/menu1.png"/></a></li>
        <li id="menu2"><a href="#"><img src="images/menu2.png"/></a>
            <ul class="submenu2">
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>           
        <li id="menu3"><a href="#"><img src="images/menu3.png" /></a></li>
        <li id="menu4"><a href="#"><img src="images/menu4.png"/></a></li>
        <li id="menu5"><a href="#"><img src="images/menu5.png"/></a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

css

```
#headermenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#headermenu ul{
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#headermenu ul li{
    width: 20%; 
    list-style-type:none; 
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    float:left;
    left:0;
}
#menu1:hover{
    background: url('images/menu1hover.png');
}
```

Hover is not working, I wonder how to make a list with image hover, I also want to know how to make a sub list when a li is hover. And if there is another list on sub list how to make it.. on pure css..

Comment: `<img src="images/menu1.png"/>` will sit on top of the background image.

Comment: @Ruddy what do you mean will sit?when i hover images does not change

Comment: It does but you cant see it. Background image is... well the background, whatever is sitting on top of the background will cover it up. (this is if the `img` takes up all of the `li`).

Comment: Try `background: url(../images/menu1hover.png);` and of course @Ruddy is right about covering.

Comment: @mdesdev its the same as my code i dont see any difference from you code can you explain?

Comment: It is working. http://jsfiddle.net/6Pp3S/ check your image path.

Comment: Difference is in the image path, in my example css document is in css folder and because of that you can see two dots and slash before image path. If your css document is in the root folder then your path is correct.

Comment: You code won't work like expected because (like @Ruddy pointed out), your image (menu1.png etc) will be layed on top of the background-image you set. This means that it might look like the code does not work, because you don't see any changes. However, it most likly does work, the only problem is that you can't see it.

Comment: @mdesdev: That is just pointless and very confusing. Image paths are not the case here.

Comment: @OptimusCrime yes i cant see changes thank you for clearing it out how do i make it go on top of the first image?so it will show?

Comment: @HakHak Look at my answer. I have explained it.

Comment: Simplest and the best way would be `#menu1 { background: url('images/menu1.png'); } #menu1:hover { background: url('images/menu1hover.png'); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't given us all the information we need to solve this I will take a guess. As I said in the comments. It could be caused by the `<img>` sitting on the background, so when you hover you cant see the background at all.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="headermenu">
    <ul>
        <li id="menu1"><a href="#"><img src="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/19euo1gaaiau9jpg/original.jpg"/></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#headermenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#headermenu ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#headermenu ul li {
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#menu1:hover {
    background: url('http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg');
}
```

Here is your code as is, the background image is changing but cannot be seen because of the `<img>` in front.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9fahD/)

---

Now here is the same code but the `<img>` being removed.

```
<div id="headermenu">
    <ul>
        <li id="menu1"><a href="#"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9fahD/1/)

We can see that the hover does work but the `<img>` was coving it up.

---

**Solutions:**

Just simply set a background on each `li` and then a background when on hover.

**CSS:**

```
#menu1 {
    background: url('http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg');
}
#menu1:hover {
    background: url('http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/19euo1gaaiau9jpg/original.jpg');
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9fahD/2/)

You could also set the display to none for the `img` when on hover.

**CSS:**

```
#menu1 {
    background: url('http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg');
}
#menu1:hover img {
    display: none;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9fahD/4/)

There are many more ways but these are two that will work.

Comment: thank you for explaining this issue is there a work around for my code or none?is there a way to make the hover image go over the img?

Comment: @HakHak Yes there are ways around it. As someone in the comments suggested the easier way would be to get a background in CSS and then have the hover change the background. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9fahD/2/)

Comment: @HakHak You could also set the display of the img to none on hover. This would also work. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9fahD/4/)

Comment: looks like a good idea that way i can still choose color for background of submenu and submenu of submenu...im still trying to figure this out though do you have idea on how to show submenu on hover?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either a background image, or an actual img for both before and after states. In your example, when the mouse hovers over #menu1 the background behind the menu1.png image is changed but menu1.png is obscuring it from view.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ldLix)

```
<body> <a href="http://www.corelangs.com" class="urlImg" title="Corelangs link"></a> </body> 


.urlImg { width: 140px; height:140px; display:block; background-image: url("http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg"); } .urlImg:hover { background-image: url('http://placehold.it/140x140'); }
```